# Sort events using date, month, year values using meta_key and meta_value

Tags: wordpress, sorting, date, meta-key

I need to sort upcoming events ascending from today, and then past events descending from today. This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure what to set the meta-key as to make it the date sorting work (or could the meta_value be wrong?). The date, month and year values are separate so I need to somehow combine them..? Right now I have the months sorting alphabetically because it's the only thing I can get to work. :) lol

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?> 
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php 

$eventquery = array (
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'asc',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'meta_value' => strftime("%Y/%m/%d", time()- (60 * 60 * 24) ),
    'meta_key' => '_cmb_e_month',
    'meta_compare' => '>',
    );
?>

<?php $myeventlist = new WP_Query($eventquery); ?>
<?php while ($myeventlist->have_posts()) : $myeventlist->the_post(); 
        $m_date = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_e_date', true );
        $m_month = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_e_month', true );
        $m_day = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_e_day', true );
        $m_year = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_e_year', true );
        $m_start_time = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_e_start_time', true );
        $m_end_time = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_e_end_time', true );
        $m_venue = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_e_venue', true );
        $event_text     = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_cmb_e_details", true);
        $event_price = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_e_price', true );
        $event_ticket_status = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_e_ticket_status', true );
        $event_thumb = the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter the array into two separate arrays: one for past events and one for future events. Sort each array in the appropriate order. Then copy the results of the two sorted arrays into one single array.

Answer (score -1):

```
$event_date=strtotime("$m_date $m_month $m_year");
$now=time();
if($event<$now) {
 echo "past event";
}
elseif($event>$now){
 echo "future event";
}
else {
 echo "now";
}
```

Comment: It is better to provide some explanations.

Comment: So I can just apply the above code along with the code I originally posted? What do I set the meta-key as?